# html form reset not doing triggering select onchange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am having a `form` where the fields need to change according to my `select`.
 But when I hit the `reset` the `select` resets back to default, but the `onchange` event on the `select` is not triggered. Is there anyway so that I can add that to my javascript?

I am resetting using a button with `type="reset"`

```
    $('#newHistoryPart select[name="roundType"]').on('change', function (data) 
    {
      $(".answerType").hide();
      selected = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
      roundTypeChange(selected); 
    });
```

Comment: Show the `reset` functionality. How you are doing `reset`?

Comment: You can use `onreset` event, which is different that `onchange`. This is the cause.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao he clearly states he's using a button with type reset.

Comment: @JoeSwindell Ok!! My bad!! Missed that part !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is, trigger the change event manually when the reset button is clicked. See [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rj19k3cw/2/)

```
$('select').on('change', function () 
{
    alert('on change');
});

$('input[type="reset"]').click(function() {
    $("select").trigger('change');
});`
```

Comment: si there anyway to achieve the opposite?
I have a form where on each select changes I filter a table.
Now when I reset I need to reset back the selects but this also trigger the select change, so I find myself in an infinite loop. 
I'm using select2 and the only way I find to reset the select2 select is the following: $(this).find("select").trigger("change");

Answer (score 7):

From my comment above, use `onreset` event instead of `onchange`:

```
$('#yourform').on('reset', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$('select[name="roundType"]').prop('selectedIndex',0);
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pp621bnc/)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you, replace alert lines with your activity code.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rj19k3cw/1/)

**HTML**

```
<select name="opt" onchange="getval(this)">
    <option value="Select" selected disabled>Select</option>
    <option value="op1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="op2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function getval(sel) {
    if (sel.value == "op1") {
        alert("Option 1 Selected");
    } else if (sel.value == "op2") {
        alert("Option 2 Selected");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("EXCEPTION !");
    }
}
```